# How does a unsigned char vector deallocation crash a program with a segfault...?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector, undefined-behavior

I'm literally deallocating a vector of unsigned chars during just normal object deallocation, and it crashes with a segfault at the vector_base deallocation free():

```
[Switching to Thread 17648.0x3528]
0x00007ff9ba0a9606 in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
(gdb) back
#0  0x00007ff9ba0a9606 in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff9ba0a5d21 in ntdll!RtlFreeHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff9b9839c9c in msvcrt!free () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
#3  0x00000000004bc540 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned char>::deallocate(unsigned char*, unsigned long long) ()
#4  0x00000000004ea87b in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<unsigned char> >::deallocate(std::allocator<unsigned char>&, unsigned char*, unsigned long long) ()
#5  0x00000000004df392 in std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_deallocate(unsigned char*, unsigned long long) ()
#6  0x00000000004df436 in std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~_Vector_base() ()
#7  0x000000000050110d in std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~vector() ()
#8  0x0000000000420dd4 in Text::~Text() ()
#9  0x000000000041c9f7 in Scene::clearOnScreenText() ()
#10 0x0000000000410a52 in Application::NextScene() ()
#11 0x0000000000412a41 in Application::update() ()
#12 0x00000000004119a8 in Application::Run()::{lambda()#2}::operator()() const ()
#13 0x000000000041501a in std::_Function_handler<void (), Application::Run()::{lambda()#2}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) ()
#14 0x00000000004cad92 in std::function<void ()>::operator()() const ()
#15 0x000000000051fba9 in std::intervalThread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::function<void ()>, std::function<void ()>, std::function<void ()>, std::function<bool ()>, long long, std::vector<long long, std::allocator<long long> >*, bool)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const ()
```

Just three questions:

How is this even possible?

What did I monumentally do wrong...?

Most importantly, how does one fix this?

Side note:

I have had nothing but problems with deallocating memory recently (specificly in this program), so would there possibly be something wrong with MinGW, or is possibly GDB not reading the stack correctly? All debugging symbols are off, and optimation is at 0;

Comment: `how does one fix this` Find the bug in your code and fix it. Don't know what other answers you expect without posting *any* code and context.

Comment: The [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) require that questions asking us to help debug code must include a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. As you've not provided that [mre], I'm voting to close this question until that code is added to your question.

Comment: The posted stack looks reasonable to me; I suspect that it is pointing to the actual location of your crash.  Crashing on an alloc or free is fairly common when the heap is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

> How is this even possible?

With undefined behavior, anything is possible.  :)  More helpfully, what's probably happening is that your heap has been corrupted (e.g. by a bad memory write somewhere), and the `new_allocator<unsigned char>::deallocate()` method tried to dereference a bad pointer in the heap's metadata, which caused the crash... but the damage had been silently done sometime earlier in your program's execution.

Another possibility is that `clearOnScreenText()` tried to call `delete` on an invalid (but non-NULL) `Text *` pointer, and so when `Text::~Text()` tries to run the destructor of the `std::vector<char>` member variable, it's trying to destroy a "vector object" that is really just arbitrary bytes that are not a valid state for a vector, with catastrophic consequences.

> Most importantly, how does one fix this?

If you can run your code on Linux, `valgrind` is a valuable tool in situations like this.  Under Windows, there are similar tools (I think one is called `Electric Fence`, but I forget what else there is out there).  Short of that, you might have to just start playing "twenty questions" with the code, by commenting out various parts of the program until the crash goes away, then adding them back in until the crash comes back, and repeating until you have a better understanding of which parts of the code are required to execute in order to reproduce the crash.  Once you've figure out what code to look at, you can start trying figure out what is wrong in the suspect code.  Very tedious, but sometimes that is the only way.